# How do I reference a schema inside another schema with Mongo, NodeJS, and Angular?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm building a MEANjs app and I have two schemas: user and a claim. I want to be able to reference user information from a claim.

Right now I can successfully access the display name in my view by using the expression {{vm.claim.user.displayName}}. How do I access the other properties of the embedded user schema?

For example, I'd like to be able to reference a user's firstName and lastName. Something like {{vm.claim.user.firstName}} doesn't yield any result in my view.

user.server.model.js

```
/**
 * User Schema
 */
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: '',
    validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your first name']
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: '',
    validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your last name']
  },
  displayName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  }
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

claim.server.model.js

```
'use strict';

/**
* Module dependencies.
*/
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/**
 * Claim Schema
*/
var ClaimSchema = new Schema({
  description: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: 'Please fill Claim description',
    trim: true
  }, 
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectID,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});

mongoose.model('Claim', ClaimSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use `User` schema in `Claim` schema you can do it like this:

```
/**
* Module dependencies.
*/
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema,
  User = require('./../models/user'); //proper path here

var UserSchema = require('mongoose').model('User').schema;

/**
 * Claim Schema
*/
var ClaimSchema = new Schema({
  description: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: 'Please fill Claim description',
    trim: true
  }, 
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  user: {
    type: UserSchema,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});

mongoose.model('Claim', ClaimSchema);
```

and `User` schema needs export statement. Replace `mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);` with:

```
exports.UserSchema = UserSchema;
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Regarding problems with proper path in dependencies, `'./../models/user'` should work for

```
├── server
|   ├── models
|   |   └──user.server.model.js
|   └── server.js
```

Comment: this looks great - I'm now having trouble defining the path to the user model where you commented //proper path here. Do i need to do some sort of module.exports statement in user.server.model.js?

Comment: What is your folder structure (I mean part with server.js and models files)?

Comment: Yes, export statement is needed. I will update answer.

Comment: Do you have `var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;` in user,server.model.js?

Comment: And another thing: when you are adding somewhere dependecy to `Claim` you need add dependency to `User` first.